# Gulp Copy content from one file to another file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to copy the content from one file to another. I am trying the following code but its throwing me an error.

```
gulp
    .src('core/core.config.local.tpl.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(core/core.config.js));
```

Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\krish\Documents\test\app\core\core.config.js'
    at Error (native)

Is there any other process that I could use to copy content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gulp.dest` expects a directory as an argument. All files are written to this destination directory. If the directory doesn't exist yet, gulp tries to create it.

In your case `gulp.dest` tries to create a directory `core/core.config.js`, but fails since a regular file with the same name already exists.

If your goal is to have the regular file at `core/core.config.js` be overwritten with the contents of `core/core.config.local.tpl.js` on every build, you can do it like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('core/core.config.local.tpl.js')
    .pipe(rename({ basename: 'core.config'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('core'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were missing the quotes only when entering the the question here, right?

`gulp.dest()` expects a folder to copy all the files in the stream, so you cannot use a single file name here (As the error says: "mkdir failed"). See: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options

When you do your `gulp.src()` you can set a base path to build the relative path from and so gulp can copy your single file to the given output folder. See: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase

As you also want to rename the file, you need something like gulp-rename: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename